# Multi field users and group

Tags: user-profile, groups

i have a list were i can add users or group to my field,
I have know if u select users in people column then i can get the name and mysite url to the user, but if i select a group in people column,then i want to get the users of that group and display name and mysite url
here is my code for geting users from multi field in list

```
                    Guid fieldID8 = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("MyField").Id;
                                    string valueField8 = item[fieldID8].ToString();
                                    SPFieldUserValueCollection userField8 = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item.Fields[fieldID8].GetFieldValue(valueField8);


                                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                                    dt.Columns.Add("ImageUrl", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                                    dt.Columns.Add("LoginName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                                    dt.Columns.Add("NavigateUrl", Type.GetType("System.String"));

                                    foreach (SPFieldUserValue value in userField8)
                                    {

                                        SPUser spuserField = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(value.User.ToString());

                                        SPList userInformationList8 = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUserInfoList;
                                        SPListItem userItem8 = userInformationList8.Items.GetItemById(spuserField.ID);
                                        SPServiceContext contextSp = SPServiceContext.GetContext(siteCollection);
                                        UserProfileManager profileManager8 = new UserProfileManager(contextSp);


                                        if (profileManager8.UserExists(spuserField.LoginName))
                                        {
                                            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                                            var profile8 = profileManager8.GetUserProfile(spuserField.LoginName);

                                            string personUrl8 = profile8.PersonalSite.Url;
                                            string userNames = userItem8["Title"].ToString();
                    string pictureURL = userItem8["Picture"].ToString();


                                            row["ImageUrl"] = pictureURL;
                                            row["LoginName"] = userNames;
                                            row["NavigateUrl"] = personUrl8;
                                            dt.Rows.Add(row);

                                        }





                                        RepeaterLinks.DataSource = dt;
                                        RepeaterLinks.DataBind();


                                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is your answer

```
Guid fieldID8 = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("MyField").Id;
string valueField8 = item[fieldID8].ToString();
SPFieldUserValueCollection userField8 = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item.Fields[fieldID8].GetFieldValue(valueField8);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ImageUrl", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add("LoginName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add("NavigateUrl", Type.GetType("System.String"));

foreach (SPFieldUserValue value in userField8)
{

if(value.User != null) // Value is User
{
    SPUser spuserField = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(value.User.ToString());
    SPList userInformationList8 = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUserInfoList;
    SPListItem userItem8 = userInformationList8.Items.GetItemById(spuserField.ID);
    SPServiceContext contextSp = SPServiceContext.GetContext(siteCollection);
    UserProfileManager profileManager8 = new UserProfileManager(contextSp);
    if (profileManager8.UserExists(spuserField.LoginName))
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        var profile8 = profileManager8.GetUserProfile(spuserField.LoginName);    
        string personUrl8 = profile8.PersonalSite.Url;
        string userNames = userItem8["Title"].ToString();
        string pictureURL = userItem8["Picture"].ToString();
        row["ImageUrl"] = pictureURL;
        row["LoginName"] = userNames;
        row["NavigateUrl"] = personUrl8;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
else // Value is Group
{
    SPGroup group = [YourWeb].SiteGroups[user.LookupValue];
    foreach(SPUser spuserField in group.Users)
    {       
        SPList userInformationList8 = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUserInfoList;
        SPListItem userItem8 = userInformationList8.Items.GetItemById(spuserField.ID);
        SPServiceContext contextSp = SPServiceContext.GetContext(siteCollection);
        UserProfileManager profileManager8 = new UserProfileManager(contextSp);
        if (profileManager8.UserExists(spuserField.LoginName))
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            var profile8 = profileManager8.GetUserProfile(spuserField.LoginName);    
            string personUrl8 = profile8.PersonalSite.Url;
            string userNames = userItem8["Title"].ToString();
            string pictureURL = userItem8["Picture"].ToString();
            row["ImageUrl"] = pictureURL;
            row["LoginName"] = userNames;
            row["NavigateUrl"] = personUrl8;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }   
}
}
RepeaterLinks.DataSource = dt;
RepeaterLinks.DataBind();
```

Hope it will help to you.

Comment: I get object reference not set?

Comment: in which line you are getting this exception?

Comment: I am getting Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Comment: you can debug the code and get exact link which throws that exception

Comment: Yes i know but i cant because i have other this in my projekt that i dont wont to deploy,

Comment: You are confusing me. If you can't deploy then how are you getting exception?

Comment: I think the problem is as SpGroup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24491/discussion-between-kalpesh-vaghela-and-therock).